# Cronjob does not save output file from docker container

Tags: r, docker, cron

I have an R script that I run inside a docker container. By itself, runs just time.

Then I created the following  script on a schedule with crontab:

cronjob.sh

```
killall Docker # Kill Docker Daemon
open -a Docker # Open Docker Daemon

sleep 120s

docker-compose up -d; # Build Container

docker exec fetcher_1 Rscript scripts/plot_daily_graphs.R #Run script

docker-compose stop # Stop Docker container

killall Docker # Kill Docker Container
```

When I manually run this script from the command line, it works just fine and outputs all files from my R script as expected.

But when it runs through the crontab job, nothing is output.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  fetcher:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./lib:/app/lib
      - ./scripts:/app/scripts
      - ./data:/app/data
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - /tmp
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse

RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get -y install pandoc psmisc git curl libxml2 libxml2-dev libz-dev libpq-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python3.5 python3-pip

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install git+https://git@github.com/ping/instagram_private_api.git@1.6.0
RUN pip3 install git+https://git@github.com/ping/instagram_private_api_extensions.git@0.3.9
RUN pip3 install emoji

RUN R -e "install.packages('dplyr', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('stringr', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('treemapify', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('png', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('grid', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('scales', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('readxl', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('BatchGetSymbols', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tidyquant', dependencies = TRUE, repos = 'http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

# App folder
ENV APP /app
RUN mkdir -p $APP
WORKDIR $APP
```

Comment: What does the script do? Does it write files to a disk? Does it send output to stdout?

Comment: @MrFlick it saves .png files to the disk.

Comment: To properly debug this, we would likely need the Dockerfile, entrypoint.sh file, the cron scripts and the docker-compose.yml.

Comment: In terms of general suggestions, I would try and check if cron is actually working within the docker container, try running a simple cron script which outputs the current time to check this

Comment: @Jamie_B I just updated the post to include the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml!

Comment: just to make sure I understand (saw some of the comments that I thnk got confused also), your cronjob.sh script builds and starts a container which in it self runs a script in the container, and the problem is when turning from running the docker commands manually to using a cronjob it doesnt do what its supose to do (which is saving .png files). please correct me if im mistaking with that asumtion, and can you please check your linux mail and journal (if you have one) for info from the cron daemon about the issue?

Comment: @n1mrod, apologies, I seem to have been a bit confused here. I thought you were trying to run a cronjob within a Docker container. It seems you are running the cronjob on your host rather than within the container. Is this correct? The only thing I would think of is that the crontab job cannot reach the docker-compose.yml file when its runs, perhaps they are in different directories. I would suggest add echo statements to your cronjob.sh file and checking the crontab logs.